# Is there some nice description about language features?

Tags: language-agnostic, language-features

I was wondering if there are some nice overviews of the majority language features existing in the current programming languages?

I am asking this because when looking at the programming features of some programming languages, such as [D Language Feature Comparison Table](http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/comparison.html), I feel like to understand how these features are related to and different from each other, in somehow organized and systematic way instead of a list, and also possibly with examples from specific languages but independent of a specific language.

Thanks for your reply and any nice reference (book or link) are also appreciated.

**Added:** I am looking for some short and concise overview, maybe just a reply is enough, not necessarily a monograph (but don't mind if you recommend it here). Details can be pursued if I feel necessary.

Comment: That's a HUGE topic and many of the more sophisticated features must be *used* to be understood - you didn't internalize conditionals by reading that chapter over and over again, did you? Also, language features are merely building blocks - they can be used together in countless ways and most of those combinations are practical in at least some cases. Would you mind to explain what you hope to gain from such a description?

Comment: @delnan: I am a lousy programmer, no matter how hard I try to be. The fundamental reason is that I don't quite get the big picture of languages.  One way is to understand language features whether classic or innovative, independent of specific languages but with examples from them, which I think, will help me to learn new languages by referring to such a big picture.

Comment: So such kind of question is not suitable at this site?

Comment: @delnan: I am looking for some short and concise overview, maybe just a reply is enough, not necessarily a monograph (but don't mind if you recommend it here). Details can be pursued if I feel necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Does [Comparison of programming languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages) or [Comparison of programming languages (syntax)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages_%28syntax%29) help? Both are from Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks! Help a little, but my intention is for description of the language features and reveal the relation and difference between them. But still I give you +1.

Comment: Annoyingly I've never found anything with much more detail, but I'm intrigued to see if anyone else can.